# Making a development site live, on Amazon EC2

Tags: migration, amazon

I currently have a live site hosted as an Amazon EC2 instance and have been working on a new site (in a development environment) also on an EC2 instance.

The new site is ready to be pushed live but I am unsure how I would approach this.

I am not overly familiar with Amazon as I am picking up from a previous developer who set all the hosting and instances up.

The live and dev sites are running on the following:

Live - www.mydomain.com
Dev - dev-www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's drill down on this situation a little bit:

1. Do you have git enabled on both environments?
2. Do you need to migrate the database as well?

Most of the situation depends on how the previous developer has set it up.

Ideally you have different branches in git and you're merging the develop with the master and then pull the master branch on the live site. Migrating the database is more complicated (I would recommend the WP DB migrate plugin (free from deliciousbrains)

If there isn't git then you'll either be forced to manually upload the new files with SFTP *you'll need to your use your ssh key*.

Or a little more convenient you can use the migration plugin from before but then it's premium version. There are other migration plugins too, but they involve more manual configuration.

If you have any more info regarding the setup let me know!